# Python run part of code every 5 min while using multi-processing

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to write a python program which does several updates on a secured API. The program itself runs fine but the issue i cant figure out is how i can request a new token every 5 min. The other problem is that i can max send 100 updates in 1 sec. At this moment this is not really an issue as i do around 20 per sec (i run on a raspberry pi 4) but we might upgrade this to a full fledged server with more then 16 cores should shatter the 100 updates per sec easily.

I got the program as far as being able to create the token and run the api calls using pool. This works fine and runs well within the 5 min but sometimes i need a full update which takes alot longer then the 5 min per token. In that case i need the pauze the pool, create and new token and then continue. The code that i have now is as follows:

```
import base64
import requests
import mysql.connector
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

CLIENTID = ""
CLIENTSECRET = ""
URL = "https://url/token?=client_credentials"
DATABASE = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="",
    user="",
    password="",
    database=""
)

### Pauze Query ###
pauzequery = DATABASE.cursor()

t0 = time.perf_counter()
pauzequery.execute("SELECT tbl_feed_BE.id, tbl_feed_BE.sku, tbl_feed_BE.titel, "
                 "tbl_feed_BE.levertijd, tbl_product_id_BE.onhold "
                 "FROM tbl_feed_BE "
                 "LEFT JOIN tbl_product_id_BE ON tbl_feed_BE.ean = tbl_product_id_BE.ean "
                 "WHERE tbl_feed_BE.ean IN ((SELECT ean FROM tbl_product_id_BE)) AND tbl_product_id_BE.onhold = 'True'")
t1 = time.perf_counter()

pauzeresult = pauzequery.fetchall()
print("Aantal producten om op pauze te zetten: ", pauzequery.rowcount)
print("Pauze query time: ", t1-t0)
###################

### Token opvragen ###
message = CLIENTID + ":" + CLIENTSECRET
message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
base64_message = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')

tokenpayload = {}
tokenheaders = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64_message
}

response = requests.request("POST", URL, headers=tokenheaders, data=tokenpayload)

response_dict = json.loads(response.text)

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/vnd.v4+json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.v4+json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response_dict['access_token']
}
#######################


### Dit onderstaande is de functie om producten op pauze te zetten
def pauze(row):
    pauzeurl = "https://api/offers/" + row[0]
    pauzepayload='{\r\n  "reference": "' + row[1] + '",\r\n  "onHoldByRetailer": "' + row[4] + '",\r\n  "unknownProductTitle": "' + row[2] + '",\r\n  "fulfilment": {\r\n    "method": "FBR",\r\n    "deliveryCode": "' + row[3] + '"\r\n  }\r\n}'

    pauzeresponse = requests.request("PUT", pauzeurl, headers=headers, data=pauzepayload)
#####


### multi-processing heaven: daadwerkelijk uitvoeren van de pauze query
t2 = time.perf_counter()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(pauze, pauzeresult)

t3 = time.perf_counter()
time1 = t3-t2

print("Pauze update time: ", time1)
######

for row in pauzeresult:
    sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_feed_BE WHERE sku = \"" + row[1] + "\""
    pauzequery.execute(sql)
    DATABASE.commit()
```

To explain the script a bit for more info. First i open a MySQL connection and run my query to get the results to use for updating. When i have those results i am requesting the first token. for the update itself i created a def where the changing lines get updated for each result and it will be called by the multi-processing process. Lastly i remove each row in the database as a separate part of the script (for this part speed or the tokens are not important anymore).

The script above will get 3 more sql queries with each there own def for updating btw. i just removed these parts as they are not functional yet because i need the token update and limiter to work.

I know the code looks not quite clean but thats mostly because i am quite new to python and use the prints mostly to check the data so dont shoot me just yet ;). I am still learning so i hope someone can help me limit the api calls so its max 100 per sec and request a new token every 5min.

Any other tips are off course also welcome so i can learn from the mistakes i am making.

Comment: multithreading is COMPLETELY different from multiprocessing. Please do not confuse the two.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. I thought it was multi-threading but it seems it is multi-processing.